# Show that the map on spheres is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

For each of the following maps between spheres, compute sufficiently many coordinate representations to prove that it is smooth.

$(a):$ $p_{n}:\mathbb{S}^{1}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{1}$ is the $n$th power map for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, given in complex notation by $p_{n}(z)=z^{n}$.

$(b):$ $\alpha:\mathbb{S}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n}$ is the antipodal map $\alpha(x)=-x.$

$(c):$ $F:\mathbb{S}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{2}$ is given by $F(w,z)=(z\overline{w}+w\overline{z},iw\overline{z}-iz\overline{w},z\overline{z}-w\overline{w})$, where we think of $\mathbb{S}^{3}$ as the subset $\{(w,z):|w|^{2}+|z|^{2}=1\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

Now my questions is only for part $(a)$ but if you want to share for the others thats ok. Since I have the stereographic projection $\sigma:\mathbb{S}^{n}\setminus \{N\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by $$\sigma(x^{1},\dots ,x^{n+1})=\frac{(x^{1},\dots ,x^{n})}{1-x^{n+1}}.$$  I somehow want to make use of this function and the function $\widetilde{\sigma}(x)=-\sigma(-x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{S}^{n}\setminus \{S\}$. But I don't see any nice way to go about it since to write $z^{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is kinda messy any suggestions? Or I'm I just doing it wrong?

Comment: What is meant by "sufficiently many coordinate representations"? Given a smooth structure on $\mathbb{S}^1$, a map is smooth in *any* chart if it is in *one* since by definition, all charts are smoothly compatible.

Comment: I'm sure either what they mean by  "sufficiently many" either the question is from Introduction to smooth manifold by Lee question 2-3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since every point in $\mathbb S^1 \subseteq \mathbb C$ can be written as $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ for $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$, the $n$-th power map, in this notation, can be rewritten as 
$$
 p_n( \cos \theta + i \sin \theta ) = p_n( e^{i n \theta } ) = e^{i n \theta} = \cos (n\theta) + i \sin (n \theta)
$$
Also, $\sigma, \widetilde{\sigma}, \sigma^{-1}, \widetilde{\sigma}^{-1}$ will be expressed as
$$
 \sigma ( e^{i \theta } ) = \frac{ \cos \theta }{ 1 - \sin \theta } \; \; \; \; \;  \widetilde{\sigma}( e^{i \theta } ) = \frac{ \cos \theta }{ 1+ \sin \theta} \; \; \; \;   \\
  \sigma^{-1}(u) = \frac{ 2u + i( u^2 - 1 ) }{u^2 + 1 } \; \; \; \;  \widetilde{\sigma}^{-1}(u) = \frac{2 u + i (1 - u ^2 ) }{ 1 + u^2 }
$$
We know $\widehat{p_n}$, the coordinate representation of $p_n$, is of the form $\sigma_2 \circ p_n \circ \sigma_1$ where $\sigma_1$ is either $\sigma^{-1}$ or $\widetilde{\sigma}^{-1}$ and $\sigma_2$ is either $\sigma$ or $\widetilde{\sigma}$. We proceed to show $\widehat{p_n}: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a smooth function (in the sense of $\mathbb R$). We know for $u \in \mathbb R$,
$$
 \sigma_1 = \frac{ 2u  \pm i (1 - u^2) }{ 1 + u^2 }
$$
the plus minus sign depends on whether $\sigma_1$ is $\sigma^{-1}$ or $\widetilde{\sigma}^{-1}$. Next, we write 
$$
  \cos \phi = \frac{ 2u }{ 1 + u^2  }\text{ and } \sin \phi = \pm \frac{ 1 - u^2 }{ 1 + u^2 }
$$
Choose appropriate domains for the inverse trigonometric function, we have $u = \arccos \phi$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
 \widehat{p_n}( u ) &= (\sigma_2 \circ p_n \circ \sigma_1) (u ) = \sigma_2 ( p_n( \sigma_1( u ) ) ) = \sigma_2( p_n( \cos \phi + i \sin \phi) ) \\
   &= \sigma_2( \cos (n \phi ) + i \sin ( n \phi ) ) = \frac{ \cos ( n \phi ) }{ 1 \pm \sin (n \phi ) } = \frac{ \cos (n \arccos u ) }{ 1 \pm \sin (n \arccos u ) }
\end{align*}
Since $f(x) = \sin x, \cos x, \arccos x$ are smooth functions, it follows that $\widehat{ p_n }$ is also a smooth function.

Comment: not done. You also need to show, the $(\mathbb{S}_{1}/(0,\mp 1) \cap p^{-1}_{n}(\mathbb{S}_{1}/(0,\pm 1)$ is open.

Comment: Why do we have $u=\operatorname{arccos}\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

Without using charts but parametrizing the sphere $\mathbb{S}^1=\{e^{\imath\varphi}\in\mathbb{C}\mid\varphi\in[0,2\pi)\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ the map $p_n:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is given by $$p_n(z)=e^{\imath\varphi n}\qquad\forall z\in\mathbb{S}^1.$$
This is a rotation on $\mathbb{S}^1$ in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and clearly smooth.

Comment: Thanks, I was so focused a looking at real valued transition function that I never thought about looking at complex ones.

Comment: @lancewellton Yes, maybe this approach does not really solve the problem showing smoothness in local representation.

Comment: Yeah we need more then one chart