# Smooth structures between spheres

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

For each of the following maps between spheres, compute sufficiently many coordinate representations to prove that it is smooth.

$(a):$ $p_{n}:\mathbb{S}^{1}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{1}$ is the $n$th power map for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, given in complex notation by $p_{n}(z)=z^{n}$.

$(b):$ $\alpha:\mathbb{S}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n}$ is the antipodal map $\alpha(x)=-x.$

$(c):$ $F:\mathbb{S}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{2}$ is given by $F(w,z)=(z\overline{w}+w\overline{z},iw\overline{z}-iz\overline{w},z\overline{z}-w\overline{w})$, where we think of $\mathbb{S}^{3}$ as the subset $\{(w,z):|w|^{2}+|z|^{2}=1\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

My question is only part $(c)$

Comment: What exactly is your question regarding (c)?

Comment: I couldn't prove It is smooth

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the map on spheres is smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497124/show-that-the-map-on-spheres-is-smooth)